# Rails Console queries working; but the same request in the app produces an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, call

Im trying to figure out how to make a simple app in Rails 4.

I have models for User, Profile and Identities.  The associations are:

User

```
has_many :identities, dependent: :destroy

has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

Profile

```
belongs_to :user
```

Identity

```
belongs_to :user
```

In the console I can write:

p = Profile.last
p.user.identities.map(&:provider).include?('facebook')

and it correctly produces the result of :false

When I try to write the following in a profiles helper method:

```
if @profile.user.identities.map(&:provider).include?('facebook')
```

I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
```

I have a logged in user in the app. I can't understand why I can successfully ask for this in the console, but I get an error when I try it in the app.

Can anyone see what has gone wrong?

Comment: What do your associations look like?

Comment: where is @profile coming from ?

Comment: Can you use the default debugging gem ```byebug``` to inspect the ```@profile```?

Comment: @jdgray - Hi - I added my associations above. It all works fine in the console - so I was just expecting it to work in the app

Comment: @Milind -in the console it comes from p = Profile.last. In the app it comes from being the profiles show page.

Comment: @MaverickTan how would I use byebug to help figure out the problem?

Comment: It is more like setting up a break point in a non-UI way. just write `byebug` before any line. the code execution stops at that point and provides you with a console with all variables available at that point. Now either you check their values or you can write next to let execution move to next line

Comment: @Vikram3891- what should I be looking for in the console messages?

Comment: @Milind hey, you can see the usage here: https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug#usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@profile` is `nil`. That's why the error occurs.

I assume you're calling the helper method from your `show.html.erb` file. in the `show.html.erb` file call the helper method like:

```
<%= helper_method_name(@profile) %> # make sure your @profile is a `Profile` object
```

in the **profiles_helper.rb**

```
def helper_method_name(profile)
   if profile.user.identities.map(&:provider).include?('facebook')
       // do something
   end 
end
```

Comment: but my #profile isn't nil. i can write @profile.created_at in the next line on the show page and it displays a time. I use # instead of the 'a' symbol because these comments don't allow it more than once

Comment: @Mei, somehow your `helper` cannot receive the `@profile` variable.

Comment: You are right. I was trying to render the partial in another view. That was causing the problem. Thank you